# javascript document.ready function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the code below on a live site. what the form button is suppose to do is transfer the parameters to a .js file and send it to the model for insertion. but the code/form wont just allow or read the .js file

```
<form id="contactform" name="contactform">
  <div class="contact-form-txt"> Contact Form</div>
  <p>
    <label for="name">Full Name *</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="company">Company Name</label>
    <input id="company" type="text" name="company" required="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="phone">Phone Number </label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" required="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" required="">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="profile">Question</label>
    <textarea name="profile" id="profile" required=""></textarea>
  </p>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  <!-- <button> submit </button> -->
</form>
```

the loading contact.js file is in the header file.    `

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo URL ?>/public/js/contact.js"></script>`
```

and the jquery file that i want to load is..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert("plssssss");
      $(document).on("click", "#submit", function(event) {
      });
});//document ready
```

Comment: check your console (F12) and see if there is some error shown

Comment: you are missing }); also missing the jquery file

Comment: is URL a constant or a variable, if variable it need dollar at the begnning and echo need semicolon at the end.

Comment: missing }); seems like a typo. Still, first thing you need to do is check your console (F12).

Comment: did you add jquery js to your page?

Comment: add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: thank a bunch to evrybody. the code now works, i made a sily mistake, i had a dot in front of the dollar sign and i was editing to code on a server so i wasnt notified of the error until i copied all the code to netbeans to indent that was when i noticed the error. thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add jQuery library.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("hello");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("plssssss");
  $(document).on("click", "#submit", function(event) {});
});
```

Comment: have re-adjusted it still not changes.

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert("plssssss");
      $(document).on("click", "#submit", function(event) {});
});
```

Comment: @sambayour if my solution helped you, please set as your solution or at least click on the upper arrow. ;)